# display the last row of html table with edit button/link

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have an html table, using while loop, it will echo all the result.

But for the last row, i want to add an edit button.
Simplified code is as below:

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['age'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['sex'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['desc'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['remark'].'</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">EDIT</a>';
echo '<tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

As you can see, the codes will print out 'EDIT' link in all the last column of each row. I just want it to print in the last row. How can i achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by last row you mean the whole data comes in one row and the button in the other row???

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, Just add an `echo '<tr><td colspan="6"><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">EDIT</a></td></tr>';` just before the `echo '</table>';` and after the final `}` brace at the end...

Comment: if you want to print 'Edit' it in the last row means? How the edit will works and what 'id' will you pass in the URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
echo '<table>';
$i = 1;
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row['age'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row['sex'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row['desc'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$row['remark'].'</td>';
   echo '<td>';
   if($i == $count){
       echo '<a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">EDIT</a>';
   }
   echo '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
   $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this..

```
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['age'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['sex'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['desc'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['remark'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">EDIT</a>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: the row has its own attributes in the database which connected them to each other. so when i click the edit button, it will also call the related info

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_num_rows() to calculate how many rows are there. And just match that no to row id. So, if last row no match with total row then you can display edit button.

```
$a=mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['age'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['sex'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['desc'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['remark'].'</td>';
if($a==$row['id'])
{
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">EDIT</a></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```